# Why my Write-Verbose messages do not appear?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-ise, verbose

I have replaced some of th ecomments with:

```
Write-Verbose "Doing somthing..."
```

and I run my script via PS ISE like:

```
.\FooScript.ps1 -verbose
```

But in the output window I do not see any of those messages.

How can I make the write-Verbose messages displayed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add

```
[CmdletBinding()]
```

at the start of your script and use the

```
-verbose
```

parameter to see verbose messages.

Read more typing:

```
help about_functions_advanced
```

Comment: You mean the top of the ps1 file?

Comment: @pencilCake yes! before the `param()` declaration. If you don't have a param add it as `param()` after `[CmdletBinding()]`

Comment: @pencilCake In ISE if you call a function with `[CmdletBinding()]` using paramenter `-verbose` it must works!